# References function in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I'm just not understand the new references() function in Rails 4
I'm reading the definition here : http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/references

It's meaby a english problem, but it's still not clear for me. 
What is the goal of this new feature? (code was working well without it before).

Must I always add a reference for each table of my includes() ?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using `includes`, Rails will usually load the results separately.  For example, if you do

```
Post.includes(:comments)
```

it will issue a query to load the post(s) and then another to load the comments with the post_id of the post(s).

It will generate a join, if, for example, you want to do

```
Post.includes(:comments).where(comments: { user_id: 44})
```

Where one of the conditions is dependent on a related table.  If, however, you were to use

```
Post.includes(:comments).where('comments.user_id = ?', 44)
```

You will get an error in Rails 4.  Any time that you're referencing a relationship in a conditional using a SQL snippet, you will have to use `references`.  To fix the above, we would do

```
Post.includes(:comments).where('comments.user_id = ?', 44).references(:comments)
```

The other option, of course, is to not use SQL snippets in your conditionals, like the second code example, but it's not always possible to avoid them.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is intended for when you're eager loading an association and you're using a string condition. Because Rails doesn't want to have to parse raw SQL in where clauses to figure out what you're doing, so `references` is intended to make it more explicit what is going on in your query.

```
Group.includes(:users).where('users.first_name = ?', 'John')
```

You should get some kind of deprecation warning if you do this.  But if you use a hash syntax you should not get the deprecation warning:

```
Group.includes(:users).where(users: { first_name: 'John' })
```

So to fix the deprecation warning on the first one, you would add `references(:users)` to it.

```
Group.includes(:users).where('users.first_name = ?', 'John').references(:users)
```

Comment: ok, so I just need to add the reference everytime I have a table name in my query?

Comment: If it's in a string. That's the important part of this situation. Like If you're using the hash-based syntax then you don't need to.

Answer (score 0):

The query method references is used to indicate that an association is referenced by a SQL string and therefore be joined over being loaded separately. As of Rails 4.1, adding a string condition of an included reference will result in an exception being raised.

Here is an example that selects all Teams which have a member named Nishant:

```
>> Team.includes(:members).where('members.name = ?', 'Nishant')
SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: members.name: SELECT "teams".*
FROM "teams" WHERE (members.name = 'Nishant')
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: no such column:
members.name: SELECT "teams".* FROM "teams" WHERE (members.name =
'Nishant')
...
```

To get the above example to work in Rails 4.1, we must include query method references with the name of the association to join

```
Team.includes(:members).where("members.name = ?", 'Nishant').references(:members)
```

However, if you were using the hash syntax with association conditions, it would still perform a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` without any exception being raised:

```
Team.includes(:members).where(members: { name: 'Nishant' })
```

Note that ordering string SQL snippets on included associations will still work the same way without the need
of references:

```
Team.includes(:members).order('members.name')
```

I hope this will help you.